# Switching from one video player to another has inexplicably broken Facebook sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

The site I'm working for has decided to switch from using Flowplayer to using JWPlayer. Aside from the obvious annoyances of switching over short codes and such, making the switch has also broken Facebook's ability to display the video in the newsfeed.

All the open graph meta tags are there. There is some duplication because of all the plugins they have installed, but the videos that use the old player (that was Flowplayer) are still displaying just fine.

We're on Wordpress, using the fv-wordpress-flowplayer plugin for flowplayer with some modifications, and the jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress for jw player, also with very minor modifications.

The test page for jw player is http://elitedaily.com/elite/videos/test-video-2/
The page for the same video using flowplayer, which works in the facebook feed, is at http://elitedaily.com/elite/videos/kate-upton/

(I'm sorry about the video. I just grabbed the first one that I found that was already on the site, not expecting to be sharing it with everyone. It should be SFW, but it definitely is a video of a female model being filmed in skimpy clothing.)

links to the facebook debugger for both pages:

[redacted -- since I'm new here it won't let me post more than two links. I thought I would do this for your convenience, but I guess I'll let you google facebook debugger and enter the urls yourself]

This are the og tags facebook is finding:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="183957921720103" />
<meta property="og:description" content="test meta" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Elite Daily" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Test video" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://elitedaily.com/elite/videos/test-video-2/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Elite Daily" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Test excerpt " />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://cdn.elitedaily.com/elite/wp-content/uploads/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/player/player.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Felitedaily.com%2Felite%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F03%2FBest_of_Upton.flv" />
```

Incidentally, I originally tried using the flowplayer swf for the og video tag (for convenience's sake), and that didn't work either. Both urls worked just fine when entered into a browser.

Any thoughts, lines of attack, or of course answers would be welcome. I'm not sure what else to do here.

Comment: I don't know if it is the cause the problem, but you are missing og:image.  Without that, I'm not sure how FB would decide what thumbnail to display.

Comment: mark4o - That's true, but it hasn't gotten in the way of displaying the video for the other player. I guess I can try that and see if anything changes.

Comment: mark4o - Actually, this fixed it. See my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Rick, out of curiosity, what were the reasons for switching to JW over Flowplayer? I'm in the process of trying to choose between the two for a client. Any insight would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in fact that it was missing the og:image tag. This is because of a difference in the way Flowplayer and JW player handle the placeholder image.

For Flowplayer, the image is actually placed on the page as an `img` tag, whereas JW player pulls it directly into the flash object, which means there's no way for Facebook to find it on the page. In this case, there were no other images on the page, so there was no thumbnail.

Bottom line: if you don't have an image or an og:image tag on the page, Facebook won't play your video.